# how to associate an approval workflow to a custom list using sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have created an approval workflow in Sharepoint designer 2010. I have created a custom list. I am unable to attach workflow to a list. My "Associate to list" is not in active mode.
Please suggest me and how could I see the workflow  result..

Answer (score 0):

If it is a list workflow i.e., it has already been associated to another list, then you will not be able to attach it to another list.

If it is globally reusable workflow, the "associate to list" option would be active.